# What modified will be in a project that is in vb.net and used backend SQL Server 2005 to run on another computer

Tags: vb.net

Tell me if I want to run a project that is created in vb.net 2010 and uses a backend SQL Server 2005.........

1. how many changes can be done in a project to run on another computer....?
2. what connection string I can write for it.......?
3. which software do I need to install on the other computer to run a project on it.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On that other computer, you need:

- a compatible version of the .NET framework (whichever version you're using)
- your application

That is, if you put the SQL Server database onto a separate, central server.

In that case, your connection string looks something like:

```
server=YourDBServer;database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

or

```
server=YourDBServer;database=YourDatabase;user id=YourUser;Password=Top$ecret;
```

There are **lots** of variations of connection strings, depending on your setup - check out the [Connection Strings web site](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for details and lots of samples

**Update:** as you would see on the ConnectionStrings web site - if you have an ASP.NET web application, you can also locally deploy your `*.MDF` file to the `App_Data` directory of your web - in that case, you also need to **locally install** SQL Server 2005 Express on your client's PC, and you need to use a connection string like this:

```
Server=(local)\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|YourDBFile.mdf; 
Database=YourDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Comment: there is a server name is differnt for on i create and on i installed a project ???

Comment: @Gulu: the server name is the name of the server machine you put your database on. If you have a network, this is typically **one central** machine that all your clients connect to. What it is - I don't know - you need to know.

Comment: @Gulu: is this a ASP.NET web application, or a Winforms app, or what?